# What if I do not want some variables to be marshalled into XML file?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

```
package jaxb.classes;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Task {
    @XmlElement(name="input")
    private String input;   // String representing the input file
    @XmlElement(name="output")
    private String output; // String representing the output file
    @XmlElement(name="format")
    private Format format; // a jaxb.classes.Format representing the format of conversion
    @XmlElement(name="taskID")
    private long taskID; // a unique ID for each task.
    @XmlElement(name="isReady")
    public boolean isReady; // boolean value representing whether the task is ready for conversion


    public boolean isChanging; // boolean representing if the user is changing the task DO NOT MARSHALL
    public boolean isExecuting; // boolean representing whether the task is being executed  DO NOT MARSHALL

    public long getTaskID(){
        return taskID;
    }

    public String getInput(){
        return input;
    }

    public String getOutput(){
        return output;
    }

    public Format getFormat(){
        return format;
    }

    public void setOutput(String out){
        output = out;
    }

    public void setFormat(Format f){
        format = f;
    }

}
```

So, here is a class that represents the pending tasks for conversion. This will be converted into XML which will contain the saved data.
However, I do not want `isChanging`, `isExecuting` to be made into XML. I want them to be `false` when they are read back.

**How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to support this use case:

**Option #1 - `@XmlTransient`**

You can use the `@XmlTransient` annotation to prevent a field/property from being marshalled or unmarshalled.

**Option #2 - `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`**

You can annotated the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so that only annotated fields/properties will be marshalled/unmarshalled.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Comment: **OPTION-1**. Just one last question: they will be initialized to their default values when I create a POJO, right ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild - That's correct.  The JAXB implementation will not populate them, so they will get whatever you initialize them to or their default value.